# How can I request my company not use my photos for promotional purposes without my explicit permission?

Tags: work-environment, employees

I got an email today notify that my company will take photos of all employees. The photo will be used for employee profile and is company's right to use it for promotional purposes.

I checked my employment agreement and see no section explicitly says that the company can use my photos (of course, taken by the company) for that purpose.

I don't like to have my photos being used without my explicit permissions, how would I state that to my employer?

Comment: We aren't lawyers, we can't offer legal advice. But chances are if its not in the contract then no.

Comment: We cannot speak to legal issues, but if you object to your photo being used this way, you should perhaps approach HR and inquire about any sort of opt-out option regarding the promotional aspect.  alternatively, ask them about supplying your own photo, which you will retain all rights as to its use.

Comment: If the question were rephrased to not have a focus on legalities, such as *"I don't want my company to use photos of me for X purpose - how can I handle this?"*, I'd vote to reopen.

Comment: Vimvq1987, I made a minor edit to remove the legal aspects (they are off topic as per the [FAQ]) - feel free to [edit] the question if this changes your intent too much (but keep in mind the [FAQ]).

Comment: It helps if you say what country you're working in - although that would be about the legal aspects ;-)

Comment: Why do you feel like you can't ask to be excluded? You know more about how your company operations and your relationship with your superiors than we do.

Comment: @Vimvq1987 - Is this in Vietnam?  Where is the company based?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*I don't like to have my photos being used without my explicit permissions, how would I state that to my employer?*

You go to your employer and say "I don't like having my photos used without my explicit permission." Most employers would then be happy to leave you out of such photos. At least most employers in my part of the world would.

Comment: You do not think there are any risks here... Especially since the OP said he has already signed an agreement that says it is ok for them to use the photos?  Do you have any links to resources that the OP could use in VIETNAM if there are reprecussions or that show thier rights and protections?  As it is this answer seems to be a dangerous assumption on your part that could cost the OP Their job if you are really wrong.